# Can you combine multiple XML files into one xml file?

Tags: android, xml, layout

So I have 7 xml files for the layouts and I was wondering if it was possible to combine all of them into one xml file? All of the layouts are similar with two buttons to go back and forth, and an image in the center.

Comment: not quite sure I understand what you mean. Can you briefly describe it? Thanks

Comment: You can use one xml file for all activity if the design is same.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a layout for your two buttons, then include it into your others views where you want with this :

```
<include layout="@layout/your_layout_name"></include>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks! what about images? Since I have 7 different images one for each page. How can I make that into one XML?

Comment: I guess you can load images dynamically into the Java code. Just use an ImageView into your xml and then load the drawable src into the Java code. 
An other way is to create 7 xml files for each images but use the include field to get the buttons part (which is the same between each view).

Answer (score 0):

use like below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width=”match_parent”
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

check this [article](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

You can use [include and merge](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) but be aware if your 7 layout are almost the same, you can probably use just one

What is the tiny difference on them ?

Comment: The only difference are the images being presented. I'm new to Android Development so some tips would be helpful :) thanks!